# calling a shell script with option and argument and get output

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to call a shell script with option and argument and get output. 
It does not work as expected. Please help. 
I am not very familiar with Python.

```
import os
import subprocess
jpsop=os.popen("jps |grep Main|awk '{print $1}'").read()
print jpsop
#print jpsop.partition(' ')[2]

for pid in jpsop.split():
    print pid
    subprocess.Popen(['/home/muthu/Downloads/check_jstat.sh', '-p' +     pid])
    print output
#  os.system('/home/muthu/Downloads/check_jstat.sh')
```

I have also tried;

```
  output=subprocess.Popen(['/home/muthu/Downloads/check_jstat.sh', '-p', str(pid)])
```

Comment: look at argparse, optparse, and getopt.

Answer (score -1):

I used sth like this in my code, to invoke commands and my bash scripts, where cmd can be "my_script.sh -p sth". Also check if your bash script have a correct permissions ;) (Chmod u+x script.sh). I hope so that can be helpfull.

```
   def run_cmd(self,cmd):
        """
        :param cmd: command to invoke
        :return: status of command
        """
        try:
            result = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as grepexc:
            return {"status": "ERROR", "code" : grepexc.returncode, "output" : grepexc.output}
        return {"status": "OK", "code": 0, "output" : result}
```